# Wanted: multi-platform shell provider for code debugging, Itanium/IA64 preferred

Tags: shell, unix, platform, itanium

Does anyone know of a UNIX shell provider that offers access to a multitude of platforms (e.g. Linux/Itanium, Max OS X/PPC, etc.) for debugging and portability testing?
I suppose that since this is a common problem that there are such services, but a Google search did not turn up anything interesting...

I am particularly interested in Linux on various CPUs, IA64 being the most important right now.

Thanks, S.

Answer (score 1):

---- The post that came back from the cold (3 year edit) ----

Launchpad gets pretty close, but it is not clear if their compiler farm can be reached by projects that are not managed by their project management software.

Most people eventually setup their own farm of servers, as simply having access to a machine might not even be enough.  Often you will want to determine exactly what software is installed, which makes it very hard to reuse for a completely different project.

Fedora and OpenSUSE have a linux-specific build farms for the architectures they supports.  It is unlikley that the extend such services to proprietary (or even non-their-distro) softare projects.  That won't do much for the HPUX / Solaris / etc OS platforms.

---- Edited after response ----

Have you tried SSH?

---- Original Post Follows ----

The problem with Shells is that even when you have a multi-platform shell, each platform has different executables installed, and different options on the executables you'll call from your shell.

For maximum portability, use Bourne shell, without extensions.  That said, you'll find yourself in some pretty odd situations; as with Microsoft Windows platforms, Cygwin will require a few path altering tools to work well under the Cygwin environment.

The key is not only the shell, it's how to use it portably.  For some guidance, look to [this chapter in the Autotools manual](http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_208.html)

Comment: The asker is looking for a service that provides shell access on various architectures.

Comment: A service as in something run by an organization.

Comment: SSH is obvious, but I was looking for a provider giving me a machine park to ssh to ;)

Comment: @satta_overflow My goodness, please tell me that your question was edited some time in the past.  I'm gob-smacked by how far from addressing the issue I was.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing Free software, look at the GCC CompileFarm: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm

Answer (score 0):

There are many hosts that offer [shell accounts](http://shells.red-pill.eu/). One example, [polarhome.com](http://www.polarhome.com/), offers a variety of environments to choose from. I don't believe they have much variety in hardware. Shell accounts cost a one-time fee of "10 local currency units" (minimum US$2 - for a user in the US it would be $10) per account (per environment).

Availability of what you're looking for is going to be somewhat limited, since providers have a number of security issues to contend with.

Comment: Yes, I know that most such providers have closed their service due to abuse :/  The point is that I don't even need outgoing Internet access on the machines in question, just valgrind (if available), gdb, a C compiler and a bunch of system-specific libraries. I figured that more people needed this to test their programs and that a demand has built up. But seemingly I was wrong. Thanks anyway